# Laravel middleware not redirecting to protected route

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a protected route using middleware which only allows access if the token sent by the client matches with the one that exists in the database. The issue that i am facing is even after successful token match the middleware is not allowing access to the protected route. The middleware code works fine by protecting the route if user tries to access it directly or without/wrong token. But when request with correct token is sent it only return status code 200 and not redirect to profile page. Wondering what is wrong?

Route:

```
Route::middleware('token_verify')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/profile', [App\Http\Controllers\User\ProfileController::class, 'profile_page']);
});
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

public function profile_page() {
    return view('partials.user.profile_page');
  }

}
```

Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class TokenVerify
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {        

        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized No Token'], 401);          
        }

        $user = User::where('userToken', $token)->first();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized Invalid Token'], 401);
            
        } 

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

Client Request in Javascript:

```
function showProfile() {

  const baseUrl = `www.mywebsite.com`;
  const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');

  if(!token) {
    window.location.href = `${baseUrl}` + '/login';
    return;
  }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      };
    
      // Make a GET request using Fetch API
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/profile`, requestOptions).then(response => {      
          if(response.status === 200) {
            console.log(`response ok`);        
          } else if(response.status === 401) {
            window.location.href = `${baseUrl}` + '/login';
          } 
        }).then(data => {      
          console.log(data);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Does the route work normally if you place it outside the `->group()`? Just asking to help debug.

Comment: Yes it does work if placed outside group.

Comment: Seems like you're not using response returned to perform the redirect. Returning a view from controller method means nothing to javascript.

Comment: why should the code redirect anywhere ? you are just getting a partial view when the token match. Can you log something before returning the partial in ```public function profile_page()``` ? i believe you should see the log

Comment: Yes the partial view should be loaded in other words user should see the profile page but its not.

Comment: The return from the controller should be a json object for the javascript function to process upon successful execution (like that 200 return status code). If you want to redirect, have that javascript redirect)

Comment: If i redirect from javascript it will make a new request and middleware code will check for the token again and will block the access to profile route.